# python when define a function why value changes without using return

Tags: python

```
>>> lst=[1]
>>> def f(lst):
        lst[0]=3


>>> f(lst)
>>> lst
[3]
```

I did not return lst in f, why lst changes?

Answer (score 1):

This is because lists are mutable in Python, and your function modifies `lst`. As a matter of fact, it has nothing to do with the missing `return` statement - all that means is if you had `x = f(lst)`, `x` would be `None`. If you would like to execute `f` on `lst` without mutating it, send a copy. Here's an example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

def fn(lst):
    print("in fn")
    lst[1] = 10

x = lst[::] # make a copy
print("X before is:", x)
fn(x)
print("X after is:", x)
print("Lst after calling fn with x but before using Lst is:", lst)
fn(lst)
print("Lst after is:", lst)
```

This prints:

```
X before is: [1, 2, 3]
in fn
X after is: [1, 10, 3]
Lst after calling fn with x but before using Lst is: [1, 2, 3]
in fn
Lst after is: [1, 10, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the way lists work in python, it doesn't send the function the list. It sends the function the place in memory where the already existing list is, which can then be changed